# Nusoap php Response not of type

Tags: php, nusoap

I try to create a nusoap client and a nusoap server. I got 2 operations declared but only one works.

There is my server_soap code;

```
$servidor = new nusoap_server();
$ns = "urn:AvertisWebService";
$servidor->configureWSDL("AvertisWebService",$ns);
$servidor->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $ns;

$servidor->register(
    "responseCorrecto",
    array("numeroIN" => "xsd:Integer"),
    array("return" => "xsd:Integer"), $ns);

$servidor->register(
    "responseIncidencia",
    array("incNomb" => "xsd:String",
        "incTelf" => "xsd:String",
        "incNif" => "xsd:String",
        "incMun" => "xsd:String",
        "incLoc" => "xsd:String",
        "incCalle" => "xsd:String",
        "incCp" => "xsd:String",
        "incCordX" => "xsd:String",
        "incCordY" => "xsd:String",
        "incText" => "xsd:String"),
    array("return" => "xsd:Integer"), $ns);

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : "";

$servidor->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);


function responseIncidencia(
    $incNomb, $incTelf, $incNif, $incMun, $incLoc,
    $incCalle, $incCp, $incCordX, $incCordY, $incText
    ){ [...]
```

And there is where i call my server:

```
 include_once "lib/nusoap/nusoap.php";
 include_once "lib/cargadorConf.php";

 $conf = new cargadorCONF();
 $cliente = new nusoap_client($conf->CONF["webServiceUrl"],true);

 $param = array("numeroIN" => 5);
 $resultado = ($cliente->call("responseCorrecto", $param));
 echo $resultado; //Must be 50 

 $param = array(
    "incNomb" => "javier", "incTelf" => "645876321" , "incNif" => "1254789" ,
    "incMun" => "municipio" , "incLoc" => "localidad" , "incCalle" => "calle" ,
    "incCp" => "36544" , "incCordX" => "1.2334" , "incCordY" => "-3.56634" , "incText" => "Hola Mundo");

 $resultado = ($cliente->call("responseIncidencia", $param));
 echo "resultado= ".$resultado;
 echo $resultado; //Must be 1
```

This code returns:

> 50

And

> Response not of type text/xml: text/html; charset=UTF-8

The first operation works fine but the second i got always this error.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this.

I got a internal problem in function "responseIncidencia" and SOAP try to return a PDOException. Then the client recibe a error on parsing.